# python regex: match last instance of character followed by certain parttern

Tags: python, regex, match

I want to edit my code below to catch all strings which END with "_C[any letter/ any number/ or nothing]"

Here is my list

```
 name_list = ['chrome_PM',
             'chrome_P',
             'chromerocker_C',
             'chromebike_P1',
             'chromecar_CMale',
             'chromeone_C1254',
             'Lukate_Aids_Consumer_P']

for name in name_list:
    counts_tail = re.compile('_C[\da-zA-Z_]*$')
    if counts_tail.search(name):
        print name
```

output:

```
chromerocker_C
chromecar_CMale
chromeone_C1254
Lukate_Aids_Consumer_P
```

expected output:

```
chromerocker_C
chromecar_CMale
chromeone_C1254
```

'Lukate_Aids_Consumer_P' should not be included because it doesnt END with '_C', how can I edit my code to handle this bug?

Thanks

Comment: a pythonic way : matching = [s for s in name_list if "_C" in s]

Comment: What python are you using? I ran your script in python 2.7.6 and the output was only these two:


    `chromecar_CMale`
    `chromeone_C1254`

Comment: I can't reproduce your code. I get [`chromecar_CMale` and `chromeone_C1254`](http://ideone.com/I5PJd8) only with your current code.

Comment: strange, I'm using python 2.7

Comment: Sorry guys, I was using an older regex, try it now, it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to remove the `_` from the last character class.

```
counts_tail = re.compile('_C[\da-zA-Z_]*$')
                                     ^
                                     |
```

So the correct form would be,

```
 name_list = ['chrome_PM',
             'chrome_P',
             'chromerocker_C',
             'chromebike_P1',
             'chromecar_CMale',
             'chromeone_C1254',
             'Lukate_Aids_Consumer_P']

for name in name_list:
    counts_tail = re.compile('_C[\da-zA-Z]*$')
    if counts_tail.search(name):
        print name
```

Because of the `_` present inside the character class, it matches `_Consumer_P` substring in `Lukate_Aids_Consumer_P`.

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```
name_list = ['chrome_PM',
             'chrome_P',
             'chromerocker_C',
             'chromebike_P1',
             'chromecar_CMale',
             'chromeone_C1254',
             'Lukate_Aids_Consumer_P']

for name in name_list:
    counts_tail = re.compile('_C(\d|[a-zA-Z])*$') # Added * 
                                                  # Unnecessary use of + in both \d and [a-zA-Z] (thanks to @Ashwani Dausodia)
    if counts_tail.search(name):
        print name
```

**Output**

```
chromerocker_C
chromecar_CMale
chromeone_C1254
```

Comment: @Wazzy, thanks this works but I have edited my original regex, I accidentally posted an older version. Could you try with the new version. thanks!

Comment: For the love of all that is holy, please don't write regex like `(x+)*`.

Comment: Unnecessary use of `+` in both `\d` and `[a-zA-Z]`.

Answer (score 0):

You find that last occurrence of `_` is followed by `C` or not:

```
for name in name_list:
    index = name.rfind('_')
    if(name[index+1] == 'C'):
       print name
```

**Remember** you can use this only if your string does not contain characters other than digits, letters and `_`. Otherwise you can use this regex:

```
'_C(\d|[a-zA-Z])*$'
```

It means `_C` followed by zero or more occurrence of `\d|[a-zA-Z]` (digit or letter) followed by `$` (end of line.)

Answer (score 0):

Use `re.compile('_C[^\W_]*$')`

You could have simply used `re.compile('_C\w*$')` but `\w` includes `_` too which is not required. So best way is to use `re.compile('_C[^\W_]*$')` which **excludes everything other than letters, numbers and _**.

Demo:

```
>>> name_list = ['chrome_PM',
         'chrome_P',
         'chromerocker_C',
         'chromebike_P1',
         'chromecar_CMale',
         'chromeone_C1254',
         'Lukate_Aids_Consumer_P']

>>> for name in name_list:
...     counts_tail = re.compile('_C[^\W_]*$')
...     if counts_tail.search(name):
...         print name
... 
chromerocker_C
chromecar_CMale
chromeone_C1254
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 name_list = ['chrome_PM',
         'chrome_P',
         'chromerocker_C',
         'chromebike_P1',
         'chromecar_CMale',
         'chromeone_C1254',
         'Lukate_Aids_Consumer_P']

for name in name_list:
    counts_tail = re.compile('_C[\da-zA-Z]*$')
    if counts_tail.search(name):
        print name
```